# Python request to download file from URL with Query String throws ProxyError HTTPSConnectionPool, Cannot connect to proxy, no such file or directory

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to use Python 3.8 with the Requests package to download an excel file from a the [RKI website in Germany](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Daten/Fallzahlen_Kum_Tab.html), but get the following error:

> ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.rki.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Daten/Fallzahlen_Kum_Tab.xlsx?__blob=publicationFile (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')))

[The link is correct](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Daten/Fallzahlen_Kum_Tab.xlsx?__blob=publicationFile), and works when clicked.

My code is:

```
import requests
resp = requests.get(r"https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Daten/Fallzahlen_Kum_Tab.xlsx",
                    verify=False,
                    params = {"__blob": "publicationFile"})
```

RKI.de/Robots.txt looks like:

> User-agent: * Disallow: /SharedDocs/Personen/ Disallow:
> /SharedDocs/Kontaktdaten/ Disallow: /SharedDocs/Kontaktformulare/
> Disallow: /SiteGlobals/ Disallow: /DE/Service/ Disallow: /EN/Service/
> Allow: /SiteGlobals/Functions/JavaScript/ Allow:
> /SiteGlobals/StyleBundles/ Allow: /SiteGlobals/Frontend/ Crawl-delay:
> 10

I'm not experienced at this type of thing. Perhaps it is not possible?

Comment: There should be some way I am trying to figure out..

Comment: Works fine on my PC,  maybe remove `verify=false`? Or shutdown your proxy software.

Comment: What is the type of that file?

Comment: Yeah it worked for my PC too

Comment: Removed verify=false, still no go. I'm in the public service here - and it's not possible to shutdown my proxy software. It's a huge headache - is there a way around these proxy issues in general?!?

Comment: Type of file is .xlsx

Comment: Or use proxy for "python requests" in a correct way.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, it may be useful.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'TE': 'Trailers',
}

params = (
    ('__blob', 'publicationFile'),
)

response = requests.get(
        'https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Date/Fallzahlen_Kum_Tab.xlsx', 
        headers=headers,
        params=params
)
```

Additional:

```
with open('file.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Proxy:

Authorization depends on your proxy server.

```
proxies = { 
    'https' : 'https://user:password@proxyip:port' 
}

response = requests.get(
        'https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Date/Fallzahlen_Kum_Tab.xlsx', 
        headers=headers,
        params=params,
        proxies=proxies
)
```

Comment: SSLError: HTTPSCOnnectionPool ...'EOD occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1125)'

Comment: please, add pip list to question @DrWhat

Comment: sorry fabel - excuse my ignorance - what is pip list?

Comment: I mean a list of installed python packages like requests, cffi, etc. To get this, type "pip list" in cmd / bash in activated virtual env if you are using it.

Comment: @DrWhat Maybe you need to set proxy with credentials directly for request?

Comment: I have tried the set proxy, which seems to at least set the proxy, but this doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use version 1.26.0, install a lower version using this command:

`pip install urllib3==1.25.11`

This should fix your problem, as the newer *urllib* uses a different function ([check here for new method](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.9/reference/index.html))

Comment: This apparently fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
import requests
# Get a copy of the default headers that requests would use
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
resp = requests.get(r"https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Daten/Fallzahlen_Kum_Tab.xlsx",
                    params = {"__blob": "publicationFile"}, headers=headers)
with open('demo.xlsx','wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)
```

Comment: SSLError: HTTPSCOnnectionPool ...'EOD occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1125)'

Comment: Have you connected to any VPN?

Comment: I doubt that I would be allowed to use a VPN. I'm in the public service, and from the feedback so far, I'm guessing it's another proxy issue, which I have no control over. Is there a way to either confirm this, or to get around proxy issues?

Comment: It might be a proxy issue but try my code with `verify=False`

Comment: Without verify=False, it throws the SSLError with 'EOD occurred in violation of protocol,' and with Verify=False, the it throws the ProxyError FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')

Comment: Strange!! This is a proxy issue please disable the proxy and try

Comment: I'm making a request to the controller of the proxy server. It may take some time to get support...

Comment: why are you using proxy server?

Comment: It is not my choice to use proxy server. Organisational issue.